# Creating non clustered index on existing partition table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have a table on which already unique index is present and it is already covered by partitioning. Now when I try to create a nonclustered index on the table, partition stopped working and I get this error:

> ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement failed. Table is partitioned while index is not partitioned.

So I created the same nonclustered index on the staging table which were being used for the partitioning but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: The error is descriptive of the problem. If you post the index definitions, we can show you what the problem is and suggest possible solutions.

Comment: Problem is solved now, problem was instead of creating non-clustered index on partition scheme I had created on PRIMARY file group

Answer (score 0):

problem was instead of creating non-clustered index on partition scheme I had created on PRIMARY file group